# Поиск по нескольким полям textbox.filter

Tags: c#, winforms

Как можно реализовать корректный поиск по нескольким полям с помощью одного textbox? Код ниже работает некорректно. То есть фильтрация должна быть по неполному совпадению `Имени` и `Фамилии`,но сравнение должно  происходить с начала строки

```
private void tbSearchClient_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  bs.Filter = "sName LIKE '%" + tbSearchClient.Text + "%' OR sSurname LIKE '%" + tbSearchClient.Text + "%'";
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Код ниже работает некорректно` ну так а что в нем некорректного?

Comment: @tym32167 добавил скриншот в вопросе

Comment: @tym32167 то есть происходит поиск по наличию введенного символа в слове (независимо от того, в какой позиции этот символ в слове находится)

Comment: а вам надо какой поиск?

Comment: @tym32167 Поиск по по нескольким полям (имени и фамилии). То есть если я буду вводить имя, будет происходить фильтрация, если буду вводить фамилию  аналогично. И даже если я буду вводить и имя, и фамилию, то фильтрация также должна работать. Но она должна сравнивать введенные символы с символами в начале поля. То есть на скриншоте выше должны выводиться только данные `Алины Крюковой`, так как совпадение по первому символу в `Фамилии`

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 - все, что справедливо для LIKE в SQL также применимо и для LIKE  в фильтрах C#. Дабы люди которые могут Вам помочь не теряли свое время, уточните требования к фильтру в тексте вопроса.

Comment: @tym32167 То есть фильтрация по неполному совпадению. Но сравнение ведется с начала `Имени` или `Фамилии`

Comment: ну то есть у вам надо 1) заменить это `'%" + tbSearchClient.Text + "%'` на это `'" + tbSearchClient.Text + "%'` (убрать первый %) 2) также рассмотрите вариант использования [параметризированных запросов](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.9.php)

Comment: @tym32167 большое вам спасибо:) Вы напишите в ответах, я проголосую за него, чтобы ваш рейтинг поднялся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Согласно [синтаксису Like](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) оператора знак `%` представляет собой любую строку. Если вы ищете совпадение с фильтром от начала текста (то есть указанный фильтр должен строго соответствовать началу фамилии/имени), то знак `%` в начале будет лишним. То есть вам надо заменить это `'%" + tbSearchClient.Text + "%'` на это `'" + tbSearchClient.Text + "%'` (убрать первый `%`)
2. также рассмотрите вариант использования [параметризированных запросов](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.9.php), чтобы избежать атаки на ваше приложение посредством SQL инъекции.